# how to show 404 page if route not found in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

i have created route group using middleware.It works perfectly.

But i have one issue where if i navigate url to

http://localhost/laravel-news/public/admin/add-post-new

this without login then it redirect to guest home page

but if i navigate url to

http://localhost/laravel-news/public/add-post-new

without admin in url then it return blank page.now my question is how to show page not found 404 page for that.i am using laravel 5.1

thank you

**update**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'admin'], function () {


            Route::get('add-post-new', function () {

        //  dd('something');
            return view('a.addPost');

            });

            Route::post('/add-post-new','PostsController@addPost');

            Route::get('/all-post', function () {return view('a.all_post'); });



});
```

Comment: There is no error thrown?Try to add the 404 error page at `resources/views/errors/404.blade.php` and see if the page is rendered..

Comment: @MateiMihai.no error thrown.i have added 404 error page but still not working.also i have that add-post-new page but it should be access to admin only not for any other users

Comment: Please tell us how the route group looks like (code). Otherwise it is just guessing.

Comment: @martinweise.i have update my question

Comment: How to handle this for rest API's? I need to send json response.

Answer (score 25):

#### update 06.08.2020

Make a 404.blade.php page in `/resources/views/errors/` folder and that page will be shown if:

- a route does not exist
- when you use `->findOrFail($modelId);`
- when you use `abort(404);`

---

instead of laravel error for non existing route:

```
Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.
1/1 NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
```

1. make 404.blade.php page in `/resources/views/errors/` folder

and then just call it with

```
abort(404);
```

For example make a route like this:

```
Route::get('/404', function () {
    abort(404);
});
```

Comment: How to handle this for rest API's? I need to send json response.

Comment: @151291 `return response()->json(['message' => 'error'), 'code' => 404])->setStatusCode(404);`

Comment: small correction: you don't need to `return abort(404);` as the `abort` function does not return anything. just remove the `return` and test it out.

Answer (score 7):

> Try this:

```
abort(404);
```

more info http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#throwing-404-errors

Comment: @Grald.thanks.i was getting that error .because of laravel project.in my fresh copy it works fine

Comment: works in laravel 9.x version, thanks

Answer (score 2):

you set an 404 route using this.then use any view file in that route

```
App::error(function(Exception $exception, $code)
{
Log::error($exception);

if (Config::get('app.debug') == false) {
    return Redirect::route('404');
}
});
```

Comment: getting error `Class "App\Helpers\Redirect" not found`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the abort(); method and create a view into the error folder, just as explained in the documentation.

Laravel will automatically fetch the error page there and display it.

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/errors#http-exceptions

Answer (score 0):

```
try{
    return view($SomeInvalidView);
}  catch (Exception $e){
    abort(404);
}
```